# Get if something can be copied in my application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In WPF I can define a Command for copying content like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" >
```

Works great and the menu item is only enabled if there is something to copy.

I want to make another `MenuItem` that is also only enabled if there is something to copy in my app. How can I copy that behavior?

Comment: _"is only enabled if there is something to copy"_ It's not correctly. Menu is enabled, if focused element implements CanExecute. [commanding-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview)

Comment: See also [application commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Sudsy1002: That is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, then the two menu items have the same criteria for if they are enabled. If that is the case, I think you could just bind your second menu item's `IsEnabled` property to the first menu item's `IsEnabled` property.

(Just confirmed that this works for me).

As an example:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="CopyItem" Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
<MenuItem Header="Something Else" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CopyItem, Path=IsEnabled}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same command "Copy", and distinguish between two different menu items by CommandParameter:

```
<MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CommandParameter="PlainCopy">
<MenuItem Header="TrickyCopy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CommandParameter="TrickyCopy">
```

Then in Command handler check parameter:

```
    private void OnCopy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == 'PlainCopy')
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```